# Invalid object serialization in json with inheritance and a list of objects when using @JsonFormat

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have this classes:

Shape:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Rectangle.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class)})
public abstract class Shape {
}
```

Circle:

```
@JsonTypeName("circle")
public class Circle extends Shape {
    int radius;
    //getters,setters
}
```

Rectangle:

```
@JsonTypeName("rectangle")
public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    private int w;
    private int h;
    //getters,setters
}
```

View:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
public class View {
    private List<Shape> shapes;
    //getters,setters
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        View view = new View();
        view.setShapes(Arrays.asList(Circle.of(2), Rectangle.of(5,4)));
        String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(view);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

After serialization, I get this json string:

```
[[{"circle":{"radius":2}},{"rectangle":{"w":5,"h":4}}]]
```

I get array in array. Can I get using Jackson following line, using the same structure:

```
[{"circle":{"radius":2}},{"rectangle":{"w":5,"h":4}}]
```

I don't want to wrap the list in an array, the list is already an array for me.

Comment: Your `View` class defines `shapes` as list. You need to change it to `private Shape shape;`

Comment: But, It's not correct. I will have a list of shapes.And with this approach, I will have one

Comment: Oh I got your point now, my mistake. Did you try removing jsonformat annotation from `View` class?

Comment: Yes, I did. In this case I get it: `{"shapes":[{"circle":{"radius":2}},{"rectangle":{"w":5,"h":4}}]}` I get the `shapes` key, but it's extra

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I tried this: `@JsonValue private List<Shape> shapes;`, but in this case I lost the keys of the `shapes`: `[{"radius":2},{"w":5,"h":4}]`

Comment: You can try writing custom deserializer.